# how to mount smbfs when IP/user/password is unknown?

Tags: mount, smbfs

If I want to use an smbfs (Samba Share) RAID I inherited, but I don't have any soft details about it beyond the mac address, how can I go about mounting it. Specifically, I don't know what IP it has (I don't have access to the layer 3 router), I don't have an account on the device, and I don't know the password of the previous user; is there a good starting point for troubleshooting smbfs in such a scenario?

Comment: You are basically saying that you know the MAC address of a file server, you have no account on said server, and want to access a share ? Do you have physical access to the server, if not, out of luck unless you find a vulnerability in the SMB protocol the server is using ...

Comment: Yup, get physical access to the system, add an account, allocate root private, ensure SSH is running and then reconfigure SMB